# Test mobile website

Tags: mobile, wamp

I am developing a mobile website and so far I have been testing it in Chrome. Now I would like to test it on my phone.

I am using WAMP and in my hosts file I have the following:
127.0.0.1  www.mysite.com

In my httpd.conf:

```
<Directory />
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mysite.com
  DocumentRoot "D:/Path/to/website/root"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

What should I type in my mobile browser to hit this website? Do I need to change some WAMP settings or anything else?

Comment: Are your phone and your PC on the same network? If so, you can try to enter the IP-adress of the PC into the address field of the web-browser on the mobile machine.

Comment: Yes, I get 404 - Forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

Add a rule to httpd.conf or to an alias file for your project:

```
<Directory "D:/Path/to/website/root">
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from 192.168.1.
</Directory>
```

MAke sure you restart apache after chaging configuration to see the effects. You may also need to put WAMP "Online" by clicking on the icon in the system tray and choosing "Put Online".

Then try accessing you page using the host computer's local IP address.